# Python YouTube downloader

Tags: python, tkinter, youtube, pytube

I'm trying to build a Youtube downloader app using Python.
When I put link on the field - appears this issue

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\truemaxevans\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1883, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:/Users/truemaxevans/PycharmProjects/pythonProject25/main.py", line 57, in __get_link
    self.downloader(link, path, name, ext)
  File "C:/Users/truemaxevans/PycharmProjects/pythonProject25/main.py", line 45, in downloader
    yt = YouTube(link)
  File "C:\Users\truemaxevans\PycharmProjects\pythonProject25\venv\lib\site-packages\pytube\__main__.py", line 73, in __init__
    self.video_id = extract.video_id(url)
  File "C:\Users\truemaxevans\PycharmProjects\pythonProject25\venv\lib\site-packages\pytube\extract.py", line 162, in video_id
    return regex_search(r"(?:v=|\/)([0-9A-Za-z_-]{11}).*", url, group=1)
  File "C:\Users\truemaxevans\PycharmProjects\pythonProject25\venv\lib\site-packages\pytube\helpers.py", line 129, in regex_search
    raise RegexMatchError(caller="regex_search", pattern=pattern)
pytube.exceptions.RegexMatchError: regex_search: could not find match for (?:v=|\/)([0-9A-Za-z_-]{11}).*

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Using tkinter and pytube for this project, I cant find this issue in official documentation and google.
Here is a code:

```
from pytube import YouTube
import tkinter as tk

WINDOW_WIDTH = 500
WINDOW_HEIGHT = 200
WINDOW_TITLE = 'YouTube downloader'
BUTTON_CLICK_SOUND = 'play'


class YouTubeDownloader:

    def __init__(self):
        self.window = tk.Tk()
        self.window.geometry("{}x{}".format(WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT))
        self.window.configure(bg='#a9dcd6')
        self.window.title(WINDOW_TITLE)

        # Create labels
        self.link_lable = tk.Label(self.window, text='Download link')
        self.link_lable.grid(column=0, row=0)
        self.link_lable = tk.Label(self.window, text='Save file as')
        self.link_lable.grid(column=0, row=1)
        self.link_lable = tk.Label(self.window, text='Save PATH')
        self.link_lable.grid(column=0, row=2)
        self.link_lable = tk.Label(self.window, text='File extension')
        self.link_lable.grid(column=0, row=3)

        # Create entry fields
        self.link_entry = tk.Entry(master=self.window, width=60)
        self.link_entry.grid(column=1, row=0)
        self.link_entry = tk.Entry(master=self.window, width=60)
        self.link_entry.grid(column=1, row=1)
        self.link_entry = tk.Entry(master=self.window, width=60)
        self.link_entry.grid(column=1, row=2)
        self.link_entry = tk.Entry(master=self.window, width=60)
        self.link_entry.grid(column=1, row=3)

        # Download button
        self.download_button = tk.Button(self.window, text='Submit', command=self.__get_link)
        self.download_button.grid(column=1, row=4)

        return

    def downloader(self, link, save_path='', save_name='', extension='mp4'):
        yt = YouTube(link)
        yt.streams.filter(progressive=True, file_extension=extension).order_by('resolution').desc().first()
        yt.streams.download(output_path=save_path, filename=save_name)

        return

    def __get_link(self):
        link = self.link_entry.get()
        path = self.link_entry.get()
        name = self.link_entry.get()
        ext = self.link_entry.get()

        self.downloader(link, path, name, ext)

        return

    def run_app(self):
        self.window.mainloop()
        return


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = YouTubeDownloader()
    app.run_app()
```

Comment: Show the full traceback of the error as properly formatted text in the question.

Comment: Are you sure you got the correct url? Try printing it and checking if it correct.

Comment: What was your url?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t-xqhn4l7Mo Im using this url

Comment: You have the same variable names for all your entries change that first, currently your program prints file extension in place of youtube link.

Answer (score 0):

On github you can find a ready-2-use Tkinter-based [YT downloader](https://github.com/Halvani/YT_StreamGrabber). Give it a try before reinventing the wheel...

[image: UI]